# GRUB2 Edit Mode problem

Tags: fedora, boot, grub2, uefi

I have recently installed Fedora 18 using UEFI. The problem I'm facing is that when I try to go into edit mode in GRUB, my PC freezes, displaying just a black square instead of text.

Unfortunately I don't have much experience with these low level problems and I'd like to ask for your help.